# About the axioms of a metric space. I think we don't need (D2) to show (D1).

Tags: metric-spaces, axioms

I am reading "Topological Spaces: Examples and Exercises" by Tetsuro Kawasaki (in Japanese).
There is the following exercise in this book:

> Definition:
> Let $X$ be a set.
> Let $d$ be a function $X\times X\to\mathbb{R}$ which satisfies (D1), (D2), (D3), (D4).
> (D1) $d(x,y)\ge 0$.
> (D2) $d(x,y)=0\Leftrightarrow x=y$.
> (D3) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$.
> (D4) $d(x,y)+d(y,z)\ge d(x,z)$.

> Exercise 3.13:
> Show that (D1) follows from (D2), (D3), (D4).

> The author's answer:
> $d(x,y)+d(y,x)\ge d(x,x)$ by (D4).
> $d(x,x)=0$ by (D2).
> So, $d(x,y)+d(y,x)\ge 0$.
> By (D3), $2d(x,y)\ge 0$.
> $\therefore d(x,y)\ge 0$.

The author used (D2),(D3),(D4) to show (D1), but I think we don't need (D2) to show (D1).

> My answer:
> Assume that there exists $(x,y)\in X\times X$ such that $d(x,y) < 0$.
> Then, by (D4),
> $d(x,y)\ge d(x,z)-d(y,z)$ and
> $d(y,x)\ge d(y,z)-d(x,z)$.
> By (D3),
> $d(x,y)\ge d(y,z)-d(x,z)$.
> Since $d(x,y)<0$, both $d(y,z)>d(x,z)$ and $d(x,z)>d(y,z)$ hold.
> This is a contradiction.

Am I correct or not?

Comment: I like your proof ! I think it's correct.

Comment: How do you know a $z$ exists in the space to allow you to apply the triangle inequality?

Comment: I think one can replace $z$ by $x$ or $y$ in the above argument without problem.

Comment: It seems to hold.  $d(x,y) < 0$ seems to be incompatible with the symmetry that $d(x,y) +d(y,z) \ge d(x,z)$ for any permutation of the $x,y,z$.

Comment: To simplify a little, you can do it without proof by contradiction. $d(x,y)\geq d(x,z)-d(y,z)$ and $d(x,y)\geq d(y,z)-d(x,z)$ allows you to conclude $d(x,y)\geq|d(x,z)-d(y,z)|\geq0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're right, I think you can also show it this way:
$$ d(x,y) \geq d(x,z) - d(y,z) \text{ } \text{ } \text{[From your answer]}$$
$$ d(x,y) \leq d(x,z) + d(z,y) \text{ } \text{ } \text{[Standard Triangle]}$$
and so subtracting $d(x,z)$ gives
$$ -d(y,z) \leq d(z,y)$$
but since symmetry holds this can only work if $d(\cdot,\cdot)\geq0$.

(This is pretty much similar to your proof)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, TTJojo.